# Weird error at LeaveCriticalSection in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, memory-leaks

I try to set vector of image and train it with SVM, but when I loop its about 2000 images from 2180 images program is break and error at code

```
void __cdecl _unlock ( int locknum)
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

I think it maybe memory leak, so I try to release all of my Mat after use, but it still didn't work.

**Edit**

Now I'm sure it error when i'm loop this code about 2084 rounds

```
void calculate_hist(Mat block,Mat_<int> hist)
{  Mat channel[3];
   split(block,channel);
   Mat_<int> h = cvCreateMat(1,1,CV_32FC1);
   int h_value;
   Mat_<int> s = cvCreateMat(1,1,CV_32FC1);
   int s_value;
     .   
     .
     .
   h.release();
   s.release();
   channel[0].release();
   channel[1].release();
   channel[2].release();
}
```

Any suggestion how to fix these.

Comment: Take a look at "img_list.push_back(resize_img);". Is memory ever released from this list elsewhere in your program? Perhaps this is the line you are looking for.

Comment: None of the code you posted has anything to do with the critical section - how is it relevant?

Comment: it not error at method read_img , but it error when loop in method compute_lhsv.